# Correct way to iterate over a list of pairs in c++?

Tags: c++

I have created a list of pairs of unordered_maps as follows:

```
list<pair<int, unordered_map<int, bool>>> calc;
```

And I am trying to iterate the list from right to left as follows:

```
for (list<int>::reverse_iterator rit = calc.rbegin(); rit != calc.rend(); ++rit) 
{
    int d = n - (*rit).first;

}
```

But The above is erroring out with message "`request for member ‘first’ in ‘rit.std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::operator*<std::_List_iterator<int> >()’, which is of non-class type ‘int’`"

Am I missing some syntax here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list<int>::reverse_iterator rit = calc.rbegin();
```

is not correct. It needs to be

```
list<pair<int, unordered_map<int, bool>>>::reverse_iterator rit = calc.rbegin();
```

You can make your life simpler and use:

```
auto rit = calc.rbegin();
```

Comment: @user3243499, Our minds and fingers don't talk to each other some times :)

Answer (score 3):

Correct syntax is:

```
using List = list<pair<int, unordered_map<int, bool>>>;
List calc;
for (List::reverse_iterator rit = calc.rbegin(); rit != calc.rend(); ++rit) 
{
    int d = n - (*rit).first;
}
```

You can use `auto` instead of `List::reverse_iterator`.